# Is there a function in spring batch to put field in a custom position of file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to create 2 steps in one job, the first step must extract the datas from Database and put them in a file, this step is done correctly.

The second step must take the file handled by the first step and process it to output a new file

My question: how can i position my new fields and data in a specific location/position in the file

Can i use the lineAggregator to handle my datas and how?

**Example:**
output step 1: 
column1, column2, column3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3

**output step2:** and the Goal
column1,column2,**newColumn**,column3
data1,data2,**newData**,data3
data1,data2,**newData**,data3
data1,data2,**newData**,data3
data1,data2,**newData**,data3

Comment: Why not just do it in a single step?

Comment: the benifit of use multiple steps in my case is to to relaunch the treatment on the second step if for example this step failed and not redo all the treatment, and also I have a very heavy treatment and these difficult to redo all the treatment, the ideal these to share this treatment over several steps.

Comment: To my knowledge, Spring Batch does not provide any such feature. However, you can write the output to a temp file and then delete / rename the file.

Comment: Reading from db, adding a column is probably faster then reading from DB, write to file. Read file, add column and write another file. File access is slow. You can do it but I would recommend a single step. I fyou really want just write a CSV, and use that file as input for the second step and write another file with the additional column.

Comment: I second @M.Deinum, I would do it in a single chunk-oriented step with an item processor that enriches items with the additional info.

Comment: hey, i will use CompositeItemProcessor instead of multi step, is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

this should be similar to writing to any new file. 
In Step 2 processor you will calculate `newData` value and populate in new POJO object and write it to file

```
 BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<CustomerCredit> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"data1", "data2","newData","data3"});
        fieldExtractor.afterPropertiesSet();

        DelimitedLineAggregator<CustomerCredit> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<CustomerCredit>()
                    .name("customerCreditWriter")
                    .resource(outputResource)
                    .lineAggregator(lineAggregator)
                    .build();
    }
```